# Many ordered queues - how to auto rebalancing streams between app instances?

Tags: node.js, architecture, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, message-queue

## Problem description

I want to deploy distributed, **ordered** queues solution for my project but I have questions/problems:

- Which tool/solution should I use? Which would be the **easiest to implement**/learn and infrastructure cost me less? RabbitMQ, Kafka, Redis Streams?
- How to implement **auto rebalancing** of topics/streams for each consumer in failure situation or when new topic/stream was added to system?

In other words, I want to realize something like that:

[distributed queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/service-bus-messaging/media/message-sessions/sessions.png)

..but, if one of my application are failed, other instances should take all traffic which is currently left with proper distribution (equal load).

Note, that my code was written in **node.js** v10 (TypeScript) and my infrastructure are based on **Azure**, so besides self-hosted solution (like RabbitMQ), azure-based solution (like Azure Service Bus) are also possible, but less vendor-lock, the better solution for me

## My current architecture

Now I provide a more detailed background of my system:

[image]

I have 100 000 vehicle's tracker devices (different ones, many manufactures and protocols), each of them communicate with one of my custom app called **decoder**. This small microservice decodes and unifies payload from tracker and send it to distributed queue. Each tracker sends message every 10-30 seconds.

Note, that I must **keep order of messages from single device**, this is very important!

In next step, I have **processing app** microservice which I want to scale (forking / clustering) depends of number of tracker devices. Each fork of this app should subscribe to some of topics/consumer groups to process messages from devices, while keeping order. Processing of each message takes about 1-3 seconds.

Note, that **in every moment of time, I can add or remove tracker devices**, and this information should be **auto-propagate to forks** of processing app and this instances should be able to auto rebalancing traffic from queue.

The question is how to do that with as little as possible lines of (node.js) code, and at the same time, keeping solution easy, clean and cheap? :)

As you see at picture above, if fork no.3 failed, system must decide which of working forks should be get "blue" messages. Also, if fork no.3 return back, rebalancing is also needed.

## My own research

I read about Apache Kafka with Consumer Groups, but Kafka is difficult to learn and to implement for me.

I read about RabbitMQ and Consumer Groups / many topics, but I don't know how to write auto rebalancing feature and also how I can use RabbitMQ (which plugins? which settings / configurations? there's so many options...).

I read about Azure Service Bus with [message sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) but it has vendor-lock (azure cloud), it costs a lot, and like other solutions, doesn't provide full auto-rebalancing out-of-box.

I read about Redis Streams (with consumer groups) but it's new feature (lack of libraries for node.js) and also doesn't provide auto-rebalancing.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 Message Brocker

For the first question you should look for a mature m2m protocol brocker which will give you freedom in designing your own intelligent data switching algorithms.

## 2 Loadbalancer

The answer to the second question you must employ well performed load balancer for handling such a huge number of 100000 connected cars. My suggestion to use Azure API Gateway or Nginx load balancer.

Now lets look at some of connected car solutions and analyze how the Aws IoT or Azure IoT  doing the job nicely.

## OpenSource IoT Solution

[OpenSource IoT Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPyOM.png)

Nginx or API Gateway is used for the load Balancing purposes while the event processing is done on Kafka. Using kafka you can implement your own rule engine for intelligent data switching. Similarly any Message Broker as IoT bridge would do better. If I were you would be using VerneMQ to implement MQTTv5 features and data routing. In this case queue is not required.
Again if you want to use azure queue you have to concentrate on managing the queue forking and preempting. To control the queue seamlessly you have to write Azure Queue Trigger server-less Function. Thus your goal to not be vendor locked would be impossible to achieve.

In single word using VerneMQ, MQTT V5 implementation with Nginx would be great to implement but as all these are opensource product you must be strong in implementation and trouble shooting otherwise your business operation would be in support failure.

Its better to use professional IoT cloud services for a solution of thousands of connected cars. This is paying of as the SLA of the service is very high standard and little effort in system operation management.

## Azure IoT Solution

[Azure IoT Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kRld.png)

If you are using Azure Solution, you be using IoT Hub where you don't have to worry about load balancing. Using Azure device SDK you can connect all the car with mobile LTE sim, OBD plugin etc to the cloud. Then azure function can handle the event processing and so on.

## AWS IoT Solution

[AWS IoT Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D271P.png)

Unlike Azure IoT Device SDK, AWS IoT have sdk for devices. But in this architecture we want to complete the connected car project a little differently. For the shake of thing shadow and actual device status synchronization we have used AWS GreenGrass core solution in the edge side. Along with the server-less IoT event processing we have settled the whole connected car solution.

Similarly Azure IoT edge could be used to provide all can information to the device twin and synchronize between the actual car and twins.

Hope this will give you a clear idea how to implement and see the cost benefit over the vendor locked or unlocked situation.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for reply! AWS IoT is not a deal for me - self-hosted or Azure based solution possible only. Azure IoT - I'm affraid that it's impossible to do with current scenario, because my tracker devices has custom UDP/TCP protocols that should be decoded/parsed (from binary form), so my own code is needed as "gateway". VerneMQ / MQTT looks good - I'm familiar with MQTT v3, but my priority goal is not lost data and delivery guarantee, so I must use QoS 3 in this case. Still I don't understand how to realize autobalancing using Nginx, as your proposal.

Comment: If you use unicorn along with nginx you can easily balance your decoder-app's load and them summarize data in a chunk to send in 1 min or so interval. for QoS 3 you can implement it in the broker side otherwise just choose a 3rd party SaaS service of mqttv5.